# can this javascript be shortened?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone tell me the method to shorten this code or an example would be great? would an array be the best method?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#parent1").css("display","none");

$(".aboveage1").click(function(){
    if ($('input[name=age1]:checked').val() == "No" ) {
        $("#parent1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect   
    } else {
        $("#parent1").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
    }
 });            
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#parent2").css("display","none");

$(".aboveage2").click(function(){
    if ($('input[name=age2]:checked').val() == "No" ) {
        $("#parent2").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect   
    } else {
        $("#parent2").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
    }
 });            
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#parent3").css("display","none");

$(".aboveage3").click(function(){
    if ($('input[name=age3]:checked').val() == "No" ) {
        $("#parent3").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect   
    } else {
        $("#parent3").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
    }
 });            
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question may need a little work. What is the code supposed to be doing? If the code has a bug, please describe it. If the code works but it needs improvement, the question belongs on [CodeReview.SE], not here. In that case, you can flag your post for moderator attention and ask to have it migrated. Good luck!

Comment: Looks like some basic CSS could be useful...

Comment: Or you could use a for loop.

Comment: Please migrate to code review rather than downvote... We all were beginners once ;)>

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your HTML and CSS more DRY. As a result your JavaScript doesn't need to register 3 times the same Handler Code ;-)

Comment: @LishaNicole Although you could also define some functions that return handlers and use a for loop to loop through it and set it up,  Thomas's idea is better.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop

```
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

$("#parent"+string(i)).css("display","none");

$(".aboveage"+string(i)).click(function(){
    if ($('input[name=age'+string(i)+']:checked').val() == "No" ) {
        $("#parent"+string(i)).slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect   
    } else {
    $("#parent"+string(i)).slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
    }
});  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the principles I adhere to in order to make readable, elegant and concise code:

- Separate data from code logic so you only have logic once ever. It can operate on different data. That mainly means that if you have to modify it you only have to modify it in one place and you won't forget to modify other places.
- put the initial state of the style in css and touch it with javascript if it has to change.
- rather than giving your 3 elements only unique classes, give them a class that describes their common behaviour, such as 'slidable' and the same for your checkboxes: 'age-checkbox'. Now you can find them all with jquery without having to reference them individually.
- make sure that your code formatting corresponds with your semantic structure (helps readability alot)
- avoid anonymous inline functions. Inlining functions in parameter lists obscures the structure of your code. If you really must do so, at least give them a name so they don't show up as 'anonymous function' when debugging and profiling.

Thanks for asking code reviews before putting stuff into production. If more people would do that we wouldn't have to file so many bugs.

This is something that might inspire you. I don't claim it's working. I didn't verify exact functionning of the jquery functions and made assumptions about your html structure. I'm not either claiming this is the best possible way to do it, but given the little information about your html structure and the time I'm willing to put into this, you should get the idea.

```
.slidable
{
    display: none;
}


<form ...>

    <div id="#parent1" class="slidable">

        <div class="aboveage1 slidebutton"></div>

        <input class="age-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="age1" />

    </div>

</form>


$( document ).ready( function documentReady() 
{
    $( ".slidebutton" ).each( attachSlide );


    function attachSlide()
    {
        $( this ).click( slide );
    }


    function slide( event ) 
    {
        var cb = $( event.target ).parent().children( '.age-checkbox' );


        if( cb.val() == "No" )

            cb.parent().slideDown( "fast" ); //Slide Down Effect   


        else 

            cb.parent().slideUp( "fast" ); //Slide Up Effect
    }

});
```